# jquery Bootgrid: get all rows data

Tags: jquery-bootgrid

I need to filter rows in my jQuery Bootgrid (with pagination).

How I can get ALL rows from grid?

When I try to do this `$('#TableId').bootgrid().data('.rs.jquery.bootgrid')`
it returns only rows in first page.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Almost there. Try this:

```
$('#TableId').bootgrid().data('.rs.jquery.bootgrid').rows
```

returns all rows data(array) that Bootgrid used right now.